# NLog WebServiceTarget: StackTrace null

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

When using a `MailTarget` with a custom `LayoutRenderer`, I can see that `LogEventInfo.StackTrace` contains data which can then be included in the rendered response. 
However, replacing the `MailTarget` with `WebServiceTarget` and using the same custom `LayoutRenderer` `LogEventInfo.StackTrace` now returns `null`

Both targets are "stock" NLog implementations, are being invoked from the same code using the same `LayoutRenderer`

Has anyone else experienced this same issue? Is there some limitation of `WebServiceTarget` that prevents stack traces being captured?

**Solution, based on Rolf's suggestion below:**

```
public sealed class MyLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer, IUsesStackTrace
{
    public StackTraceUsage StackTraceUsage => StackTraceUsage.Max; 

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog only captures and provides StackTrace for a target, if you are using a layoutrenderer like Ex. `${callsite}`.

If you have a custom layout-renderer, then you can inherit from `NLog.Internal.IUsesStackTrace` (And return `StackTraceUsage.Max`)